# How do I read only one type from a single-line file with multiple types?

Tags: c++, stdio

So I have a text file with a single line that looks like this:

> **Steve 3 Sylvia 7 Craig 14 Lisa 14 Brian 4 Charlotte 9 Jordan 6**

What I'm attempting to do is read each integer from the text file. I've tried some code which looks like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        int a;

        ifstream inStream;
        inStream.open("file.txt");

// case for file open failing
        if ( inStream.fail() )
        {
            cout << "File open failed.\n";
            exit(1);
            }

//attempting to read each integer and print it to see if it worked right
            while( inStream.good() )
            {
                inStream>>a;
                    cout<<a;

             }


         return 0;
     }
```

I know this is pretty simple to do when the whole file consists of just integers, or if the entire file wasn't one line, however I'm having trouble with this case

Comment: Files don't contain types. Or objects of types. They contain _bytes_. How you parse those bytes into object representations is up to you...

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the format will be like **name number name number** ... then you can do something like this:

```cpp
int a;
string name;
// read name first then number
while( inStream >> name >> a )
{
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

You can't jump over the names while reading with **>>**, but you can read them and do nothing with them.

Comment: Worked now, thanks! Would you know what to do if there was no real pattern in the text?

Comment: It depends on what exactly you want to achieve. A text file is just a sequence of symbols(including space, endline etc.), there are no types there, only symbols in order. And you can read those symbols in order. If you are reading them into string s(with inStream >> s) then it just reads symbol by symbol and stores them in s until it sees space of endline symbol, similar thing is done while reading into int, but with different logic. All that functionality is build on reading single character.

Comment: So if there's no pattern I can suggest to read chunks into string s (inStream >> s) and each time check manually if it looks like a  valid number(contains only '0'-'9' symbols), then convert to integer if it is a valid number.

Comment: But you have to be sure that those numbers will be surrounded by delimiters like space or endline, so the content of a file should not be like "steve15 sylvia 7craign 14", otherwise you will have to read symbol by symbol to achieve what you want.

Comment: In the example given, it would safer and preferred to use `while( inStream >> name >> a) { cout << a << endl; }` instead.

Comment: @AlexandreCxovrebovi your edit is incorrect. `good()` does not take an input parameter. You need to remove `good()` completely and let the `if` evaluate the result of `operator>>` directly, exactly as I showed. I have fixed it for you.

Comment: Yep sorry, didn't pay attention while editing and forgot to remove it. Thanks again for noticing.

Answer (score 1):

A basic regex search can easly solve the problem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
  std::string buf = "Steve 3 Sylvya 7 Craig 14 Lisa 14 Brian 4 Charlotte 9 Jordan 6";
  std::regex all_digit("\\d+");
  std::smatch taken;
  while(std::regex_search(buf, taken, all_digit, std::regex_constants::match_any)) {
    for(auto x : taken)
      std::cout << x << '\n';
    buf = taken.suffix().str();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Please adapt the above code to your needs. Switch the string with the buffer taken from the file.